# LNK1181 cannot open input file

Tags: visual-studio-2017, libuv

I have these errors on visual studio 2017 whenever i try to build/debug the project:

> LNK1181 cannot open input file 'C:\Program Files\libuv\Release\lib\libuv.lib

And this warning dialog:

> Unable to start program
>       xmrig-2.3.1\build\Debug\xmrig.exe

The project is here : https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig

How i can solve it? Thank you!

---

Update:
The path is like:

it's like C:\Program Files\libuv\libuv.lib in my computer  not C:\Program Files\libuv\Release\lib\libuv.lib

How i can edit it in visual studio?

Comment: To give an old cliche, have you tried restarting?  Sounds to me like the file is locked by another application possibly?  If the problem is local, then it's really only a matter of restarting / killing the process with libuv.lib locked.

Comment: i restarted it, clean it.. didn't work. i will try to kill process thank you

Comment: Restarted the PC , i run vs as admin didn't solve the problem,

Comment: Have you tried actually renaming the file libuv.lib on the file system?  Also, check if it exists.  It's absurd but I've seen plenty of absurd problems like this.

Comment: it's like C:\Program Files\libuv\libuv.lib how i can change the path in vs?

Comment: It is not obvious how libuv ended up there or why you even need it to build the library.  But you'll probably have better luck if you copy it to c:\program files (x86) so 32-bit build tools can find it.